# Write .net web service consumes from SAP

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I need to write .Net (C#) a web service which consumes from SAP side. I wrote the c# web service but problem is that need to add HTTP request header. Actually I don't know how to add HTTP Request header to web service? I added SOAP Header but SAP side need HTTP request Header.

Sample Code:

```
    public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
         public class AuthSoapHeader : SoapHeader
         {
              public AuthSoapHeader() { }
    
              public string Username = string.Empty;
              public string Password = string.Empty;
         }

        [WebMethod]
        [SoapHeader("AuthHeader")]
        public List<Response> Testmethod(TestClass testData)
        {

            if ( AuthHeader.Username == "testuser" && AuthHeader.Password == "testpawd")
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Please anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: If you show us your code we might be able to help you, but without an idea of what you've done it's hard to comment.

Comment: @Mike Parkhill I added sample code

Answer (score 0):

I've already worked on a similar solution, but in VB.net. On that solution, i've created a separated layer(project) to deal with the SAP communication and data retrieval. 
The code bellow is the webservice snippet with SOAP authentication.

```
<SoapHeader("Authentication", Required:=True)> _
<WebMethod(Description:="SAP search")> _
Public Function SampleSearch() As String

    Dim objSearch As New clsSapSearch
    Dim dsReturn As New DataSet
    dsReturn.Tables.Add(objSearch.Search("parameter1", "parameter2"))

    Return GetXmlIncludingNull(dsReturn)

End Function
```